# Git Built On Android Throws 'undefined reference to dlopen' Error

Tags: android, git, libcurl, gcc4.8

I'm building git on my Android device in KBOX2 using gcc 4.8 with libcurl, which I also built on device.  I'm building with libcurl for http/https support

Configure, make and make install run successfully.  However, when I try to clone an https git, I get the following error:

fakechroot: dlopen: undefined symbol: dlopen

I'm aware that fakechroot [only intercepts dynamic libc calls](http://kevinboone.net/kbox2_how_it_works.html). I've dynamically linked all of the supporting libs.  What could be causing this error and how do I fix it?

Please let me know what I should post (env vars, configure and/or make options) that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be rooted in curl...which also threw the same error when performing basic operations.

Short Answer:  I scrapped everything...openssl, curl, git...and started over. I made sure that I included -ldl and -lc with all of the builds and I made sure to specify -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker in the LDFLAGS with all of the builds.

Since I'm still learning about Linux and Android in general and various aspects of configure and make in particular, I'm not sure what fixed the problem. I'll leave this open in case someone with more knowledge wants to chime in.